# ¿Es correcto decir "Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario me hubierais asesinado"?

Tags: subjuntivo

En la siguiente frase:

> Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario me hubierais asesinado

¿Os parece normal el uso del pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo en la oración principal si el verbo de la subordinada va en presente?

Gracias

Comment: En Colombia diríamos "Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario me **hubieras** asesinado" aunque es más frecuente invertir el sujeto "Si llego **yo** a hacer ese comentario me **hubieras** asesinado"

Comment: @DGaleano ¿y tienen ambas frases la misma connotación? Para mí, mover _yo_ tan adelante en la segunda da aún más potencia a esa palabra y connota cierto victimismo incluso.

Comment: @fedorqui Entiendo tu inquietud. Escribirla de una u otra forma parecería cambiar un poco el sentido, pero yo diría que en el lenguaje hablado la connotación que tenga la frase dependerá más del énfasis que se haga sobre una u otra palabra.  Para mi es más natural usar "yo" adelante y ahora que lo considero en Colombia podría incluso ser más frecuente decir "Si **yo** llego a ..."

Comment: @DGaleano entiendo y comparto que en el lenguaje hablado será determinante la palabra que se marque con mayor intensidad. Leyendo, a mí me parecen menos incisivas _Si yo llego_ y _Si llego a hacer yo_. Por contra, _Si llego yo..._ es la que más me parece que incide en el _yo_.

Answer (score 6):

No, porque la implicancia de la segunda cláusula alude a que *no me asesinó.* Por tanto, si esto no pasó, no puedes decir *si llego*, porque es una acción del presente.

Naturalmente se suele poner (al menos acá en Chile)

> Si **hubiese/hubiera** llegado a hacer ese comentario, me **habrías** asesinado. (Pero no lo hice, así que no me asesinaste.)

Comment: Curioso, en España este uso es perfectamente idiomático. ¿Podrías añadir el país, a ver si surgen diferencias regionales?

Comment: @Yay Ahí lo agregué; Me sorprende que sea idiomático en tu país. ¡Yo lo encuentro horrible!

Comment: Puedo corroborar la opinión de @Ustanak: en Chile no usamos _hubierais_ ni _habríais_. Creo (aunque no estoy seguro) que _hubieras_ y _habrías_ son de uso general en Latinoamérica.

Comment: @Ustanak, **ojo**: hubierais es plural, el equivalente sería _ustedes_ me _habrían_ asesinado

Answer (score 3):

Aquí en Cataluña, España, es correcto. Quizá se use más:

> Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario me **habríais** asesinado.

Aunque es posible que eso se deba a la influencia del catalán
 (En catalán sí que se usa mucho más el condicional que el pretérito imperfecto en este caso)

Comment: Yo soy catalán también, pero yo diría (a mí me suena mejor): Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario me **hubieseis** asesinado

Answer (score 0):

*Consta explicar de un principio que mi respuesta está formulada según patrones de conversación en Español de México.*

A mí me llega extraña la expresión en la forma tal como está. Presiento por el inicio del enunciado "Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario..." que el comentario en sí no ha llegado a suceder. Por lo tanto, la consecuencia aún queda en el futuro. De ser eso cierto, mi entendimiento de la lengua quisiera expresar:

> Si llego a hacer yo ese comentario, me ***asesinarían*** (ustedes).

Por lo contrario, si se tratara de un comentario que no llegó a suceder aunque podría haber sucedido, el final del enunciado es adecuado, y es el principio que debe cambiar de tal forma:

> Si ***hubiese*** llegado a hacer ese comentario, me ***habrían*** asesinado (ustedes).